# How to put two tables in one landscape page

Tags: tables, landscape

I have two consecutive tables and since they are wide I want to have them in a landscape page. But it doesn't show both of them in one page. here is the code I'm using:

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{}\label{sup1}
\begin{tabular}
...
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{}\label{sup2}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}
...
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: I do not want them to be side-by-side. After one finishes, I want the other table to start.

Comment: The `center` environment adds some extra vertical space that may cause one table to flow over to the next page; see [Should I use center or centering for figures?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651/5764) Also, since `table` is a float, it will float around your document based on the amount of space allowed for floats on a page. Would you be able to provide the actual table as well as the package you're using to obtain your output? That is, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: If I can make the margin wider it will fit but I don't know how to do it!

Comment: if both tables really do fit on one page, then just include them in a single float.  if you keep a blank line between the first

Comment: anna, as @barbarabeeton commented, you can have two `\caption`s (and `\label`s) in a single float.

Answer (score 5):

if both tables really do fit on one page, then just include them in a single float.

if you put a blank line and some vertical space, say `\medskip`, between the first `\end{tabular}` and the second `\begin{tabular}` they should be set one above the other, not side by side.

you'll need to force them to start on a new page.  this can be done by

```
\usepackage{afterpage,lscape}
...
\afterpage{\clearpage % begin landscape tables
   \begin{landscape}
   ... [tables]
   \end{landscape}
} % end landscape tables
```

within this scope, if you have more than one page of tables, you can use `\newpage`.  in fact, you can even use `longtable` (provided you `\usepackage{longtable}`).

Answer (score 3):

If your concern is to keep the two tables on your landscape page *at all costs*, then using a float might be the wrong option. The reason for this is because LaTeX only allows a certain number of floats on a page and floats may only take up a certain portion of the page. The quantities and parameters governing the placement of floats on a page is explained in detail in [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764)

If this is indeed the problem (tables floating to other pages because they don't fit the parameter requirements), I would suggest *not* making the tables float by using functionality provided by the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) (or the lite [`capt-of` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of)) via `\captionof`. This allows you to have the captioning capability of floats, without having to use a float:

```
\begin{landscape}
\centering
\captionof{table}{This is a table.}\label{sup1}\par
\begin{tabular}
...
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\captionof{table}{This is another table.}\label{sup2}\par
\begin{tabular}
...
\end{tabular}
\end{landscape}
```

If, on the other hand, you just need a little more vertical space on the page to fit the second table, you could use `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}` to have one extra line (or use any length to enlarge the page as much as you want).

Answer (score 2):

One option for doing that consist on writing two "tabular" inside a "table".
This is what I mean:

```
\usepackage{lscape}
...

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
    ...
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:addlabel1}%

  \vspace{1cm} %space between tables

  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
    ...
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel2}%
\end{table}%
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: This is exactly what [babara beeton already answered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41366/9057) in her first sentence, isn't it?