# Two sideways tables on one page

Tags: tables, rotating

I want to put two sideways tables next to eachother. For landscape this is possible by putting the two tabulars in one landscape ([How to put two tables in one landscape page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41332/how-to-put-two-tables-in-one-landscape-page)). Is something like this also possible for sidewaystables?

Both tables are a page length wide, but not so long, so I want to put them horizontally next to each other.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm confused by the way you describe the tables' specifications: If they're each as wide as a page, how can they fit next two each other on a page? Please clarify.

Comment: @Mico by turning them. Their height is less than the width of a page, and their width is less than the height of a page.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `sidewaystable` environment doesn't limit you to one table per page. As long as the `tabular` (or `tabular*`, etc.) environments fit in a single (rotated) page, you can have more than one of these environments on a page typeset in a `sidewaystable` construct.

For instance, the following code places two simple `tabular*` environments one below the other (or, if you will, side by side...) on one page. Note that they can be given captions and be cross-referenced like any other tabular construct.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating,booktabs}
\begin{document}
Cross-references to tables \ref{tab:1} and \ref{tab:2}.
\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{First table} \label{tab:1}

\smallskip
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{9}{c}}
\toprule
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & j \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip\bigskip  % provide some separation between the two tables
\caption{Second table} \label{tab:2}

\smallskip
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{9}{c}}
\toprule
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & j \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps using the [`hvfloat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hvfloat) package?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hvfloat}

\begin{document}    

\hvFloat[rotAngle=90,nonFloat=true,capWidth=w]%
{table}%
{\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
header1 & header2 \\
\midrule
text1 & text2 \\
text3 & text4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}%
{A first rotated table}%
{tab:testa}

\vspace*{30pt}

\hvFloat[rotAngle=90,nonFloat=true,capWidth=w]%
{table}%
{\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
header3 & header4 & header5 \\
\midrule
text5 & text6 & text7 \\
text8 & text9 & text10 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}%
{Another rotated table next to the first one}%
{tab:testb}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hvfloat}

\begin{document}    

\hvFloat[rotAngle=90,nonFloat=true,capWidth=w]%
{table}%
{\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
header1 & header2 \\
\midrule
text1 & text2 \\
text3 & text4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}%
{A first rotated table}%
{tab:testa}\qquad
\hvFloat[rotAngle=90,nonFloat=true,capWidth=w]%
{table}%
{\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
header3 & header4 & header5 \\
\midrule
text5 & text6 & text7 \\
text8 & text9 & text10 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}%
{Another rotated table next to the first one}%
{tab:testb}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to put them next to each other instead of on top with hvfloat? They are two very wide tables, but not so long.

Comment: @NiekdeKlein please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Reproducing here [an answer](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3453#) that I came across on latex.org

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}

\parindent0em

\begin{document}
   \begin{sidewaystable}
     \caption{Table One}\label{tab:one}
     \centering
     \begin{tabular}{*{4}{c}} \toprule
       Table Head & Table Head & Table Head & Table Head \\ \midrule
       Some Values & Some Values & Some Values & Some Values \\
       Some Values & Some Values & Some Values & Some Values \\
       Some Values & Some Values & Some Values & Some Values \\
       Some Values & Some Values & Some Values & Some Values \\ \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}

    \vspace{2\baselineskip}
    \caption{Table Two}\label{tab:two}
     \centering
     \begin{tabular}{*{4}{c}} \toprule
       Table Head & Table Head & Table Head & Table Head \\ \midrule
       Some Values & Some Values & Some Values & Some Values \\
       Some Values & Some Values & Some Values & Some Values \\
       Some Values & Some Values & Some Values & Some Values \\
       Some Values & Some Values & Some Values & Some Values \\ \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}
   \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```