# Two large sideways tables on one page

Tags: tables, minipage, rotating

I'm new to Latex and I've got two very large sideways tables.
I want to put them into one page and used the minipage environment.
But the result is way too large for the page and now I'm a bit frustrated :)

I tried it with the solution to this question but the result is nearly the same.
[Two sideways tables on one page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133743/two-sideways-tables-on-one-page)

Below my code. What I'm I doing wrong?

I would be thankful for any help.

Cheers,
Silvano

```
\newpage
\thispagestyle{firststyle}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}
\begin{sidewaystable}[h!]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\caption[test3]{test3}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc} \toprule
\hline\hline
YTM & 1Y & 2Y & 3Y & 4Y & 5Y & 6Y & 7Y & 8Y & 9Y & 10Y & 11Y & 12Y & 13Y & 14Y & 15Y & 16Y & 17Y & 18Y & 18Y & 20Y & 21Y & 22Y & 23Y & 24Y & 25Y & 26Y & 27Y & 28Y & 29Y & 30Y \\
\hline
0\% & 110.00 & 120.00 & 130.00 & 140.00 & 150.00 & 160.00 & 170.00 & 180.00 & 190.00 & 200.00 & 210.00 & 220.00 & 230.00 & 240.00 & 250.00 & 260.00 & 270.00 & 280.00 & 290.00 & 300.00 & 310.00 & 320.00 & 330.00 & 340.00 & 350.00 & 360.00 & 370.00 & 380.00 & 390.00 & 400.00 \\
1\% & 108.91 & 117.73 & 126.47 & 135.12 & 143.68 & 152.16 & 160.55 & 168.87 & 177.09 & 185.24 & 193.31 & 201.30 & 209.20 & 217.03 & 224.79 & 232.46 & 240.06 & 247.58 & 255.03 & 262.41 & 269.71 & 276.94 & 284.10 & 291.19 & 298.21 & 305.16 & 312.04 & 318.85 & 325.59 & 332.27 \\
2\% & 107.84 & 115.53 & 123.07 & 130.46 & 137.71 & 144.81 & 151.78 & 158.60 & 165.30 & 171.86 & 178.29 & 184.60 & 190.79 & 196.85 & 202.79 & 208.62 & 214.33 & 219.94 & 225.43 & 230.81 & 236.09 & 241.26 & 246.34 & 251.31 & 256.19 & 260.97 & 265.66 & 270.25 & 274.76 & 279.17 \\
3\% & 106.80 & 113.39 & 119.80 & 126.02 & 132.06 & 137.92 & 143.61 & 149.14 & 154.50 & 159.71 & 164.77 & 169.68 & 174.44 & 179.07 & 183.57 & 187.93 & 192.16 & 196.27 & 200.27 & 204.14 & 207.91 & 211.56 & 215.11 & 218.55 & 221.89 & 225.14 & 228.29 & 231.35 & 234.32 & 237.20 \\
4\% & 105.77 & 111.32 & 116.65 & 121.78 & 126.71 & 131.45 & 136.01 & 140.40 & 144.61 & 148.67 & 152.56 & 156.31 & 159.91 & 163.38 & 166.71 & 169.91 & 172.99 & 175.96 & 178.80 & 181.54 & 184.17 & 186.71 & 189.14 & 191.48 & 193.73 & 195.90 & 197.98 & 199.98 & 201.90 & 203.75 \\
5\% & 104.76 & 109.30 & 113.62 & 117.73 & 121.65 & 125.38 & 128.93 & 132.32 & 135.54 & 138.61 & 141.53 & 144.32 & 146.97 & 149.49 & 151.90 & 154.19 & 156.37 & 158.45 & 160.43 & 162.31 & 164.11 & 165.82 & 167.44 & 168.99 & 170.47 & 171.88 & 173.22 & 174.49 & 175.71 & 176.86 \\
6\% & 103.77 & 107.33 & 110.69 & 113.86 & 116.85 & 119.67 & 122.33 & 124.84 & 127.21 & 129.44 & 131.55 & 133.54 & 135.41 & 137.18 & 138.85 & 140.42 & 141.91 & 143.31 & 144.63 & 145.88 & 147.06 & 148.17 & 149.21 & 150.20 & 151.13 & 152.01 & 152.84 & 153.62 & 154.36 & 155.06 \\
7\% & 102.80 & 105.42 & 107.87 & 110.16 & 112.30 & 114.30 & 116.17 & 117.91 & 119.55 & 121.07 & 122.50 & 123.83 & 125.07 & 126.24 & 127.32 & 128.34 & 129.29 & 130.18 & 131.01 & 131.78 & 132.51 & 133.18 & 133.82 & 134.41 & 134.96 & 135.48 & 135.96 & 136.41 & 136.83 & 137.23 \\
8\% & 101.85 & 103.57 & 105.15 & 106.62 & 107.99 & 109.25 & 110.41 & 111.49 & 112.49 & 113.42 & 114.28 & 115.07 & 115.81 & 116.49 & 117.12 & 117.70 & 118.24 & 118.74 & 119.21 & 119.64 & 120.03 & 120.40 & 120.74 & 121.06 & 121.35 & 121.62 & 121.87 & 122.10 & 122.32 & 122.52 \\
9\% & 100.92 & 101.76 & 102.53 & 103.24 & 103.89 & 104.49 & 105.03 & 105.53 & 106.00 & 106.42 & 106.81 & 107.16 & 107.49 & 107.79 & 108.06 & 108.31 & 108.54 & 108.76 & 108.95 & 109.13 & 109.29 & 109.44 & 109.58 & 109.71 & 109.82 & 109.93 & 110.03 & 110.12 & 110.20 & 110.27 \\
10\% & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 \\
11\% & 99.10 & 98.29 & 97.56 & 96.90 & 96.30 & 95.77 & 95.29 & 94.85 & 94.46 & 94.11 & 93.79 & 93.51 & 93.25 & 93.02 & 92.81 & 92.62 & 92.45 & 92.30 & 92.16 & 92.04 & 91.92 & 91.82 & 91.73 & 91.65 & 91.58 & 91.51 & 91.45 & 91.40 & 91.35 & 91.31 \\
12\% & 98.21 & 96.62 & 95.20 & 93.93 & 92.79 & 91.78 & 90.87 & 90.06 & 89.34 & 88.70 & 88.12 & 87.61 & 87.15 & 86.74 & 86.38 & 86.05 & 85.76 & 85.50 & 85.27 & 85.06 & 84.88 & 84.71 & 84.56 & 84.43 & 84.31 & 84.21 & 84.11 & 84.03 & 83.96 & 83.89 \\
13\% & 97.35 & 95.00 & 92.92 & 91.08 & 89.45 & 88.01 & 86.73 & 85.60 & 84.61 & 83.72 & 82.94 & 82.25 & 81.63 & 81.09 & 80.61 & 80.19 & 79.81 & 79.48 & 79.19 & 78.93 & 78.70 & 78.49 & 78.31 & 78.15 & 78.01 & 77.88 & 77.77 & 77.68 & 77.59 & 77.51 \\
14\% & 96.49 & 93.41 & 90.71 & 88.35 & 86.27 & 84.45 & 82.85 & 81.44 & 80.21 & 79.14 & 78.19 & 77.36 & 76.63 & 75.99 & 75.43 & 74.94 & 74.51 & 74.13 & 73.80 & 73.51 & 73.25 & 73.03 & 72.83 & 72.66 & 72.51 & 72.38 & 72.26 & 72.16 & 72.07 & 71.99 \\
15\% & 95.65 & 91.87 & 88.58 & 85.73 & 83.24 & 81.08 & 79.20 & 77.56 & 76.14 & 74.91 & 73.83 & 72.90 & 72.08 & 71.38 & 70.76 & 70.23 & 69.76 & 69.36 & 69.01 & 68.70 & 68.44 & 68.21 & 68.01 & 67.83 & 67.68 & 67.55 & 67.43 & 67.33 & 67.25 & 67.17 \\
16\% & 94.83 & 90.37 & 86.52 & 83.21 & 80.35 & 77.89 & 75.77 & 73.94 & 72.36 & 71.00 & 69.83 & 68.82 & 67.95 & 67.19 & 66.55 & 65.99 & 65.51 & 65.09 & 64.74 & 64.43 & 64.16 & 63.93 & 63.73 & 63.56 & 63.42 & 63.29 & 63.18 & 63.09 & 63.01 & 62.94 \\
17\% & 94.02 & 88.90 & 84.53 & 80.80 & 77.60 & 74.88 & 72.54 & 70.55 & 68.85 & 67.39 & 66.15 & 65.08 & 64.17 & 63.39 & 62.73 & 62.16 & 61.68 & 61.26 & 60.91 & 60.61 & 60.35 & 60.13 & 59.94 & 59.77 & 59.64 & 59.52 & 59.42 & 59.33 & 59.26 & 59.19 \\
18\% & 93.22 & 87.47 & 82.61 & 78.48 & 74.98 & 72.02 & 69.51 & 67.38 & 65.58 & 64.05 & 62.75 & 61.65 & 60.72 & 59.94 & 59.27 & 58.70 & 58.22 & 57.81 & 57.47 & 57.18 & 56.93 & 56.72 & 56.54 & 56.39 & 56.26 & 56.16 & 56.06 & 55.99 & 55.92 & 55.87 \\
19\% & 92.44 & 86.08 & 80.74 & 76.25 & 72.48 & 69.31 & 66.65 & 64.41 & 62.53 & 60.95 & 59.62 & 58.51 & 57.57 & 56.78 & 56.12 & 55.56 & 55.09 & 54.70 & 54.37 & 54.09 & 53.86 & 53.66 & 53.50 & 53.36 & 53.24 & 53.15 & 53.06 & 52.99 & 52.94 & 52.89 \\
20\% & 91.67 & 84.72 & 78.94 & 74.11 & 70.09 & 66.74 & 63.95 & 61.63 & 59.69 & 58.08 & 56.73 & 55.61 & 54.67 & 53.89 & 53.25 & 52.70 & 52.25 & 51.88 & 51.57 & 51.30 & 51.09 & 50.91 & 50.75 & 50.63 & 50.52 & 50.44 & 50.36 & 50.30 & 50.25 & 50.21\\
\hline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\caption[test4]{test4}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc} \toprule
\hline\hline
YTM & 1Y & 2Y & 3Y & 4Y & 5Y & 6Y & 7Y & 8Y & 9Y & 10Y & 11Y & 12Y & 13Y & 14Y & 15Y & 16Y & 17Y & 18Y & 18Y & 20Y & 21Y & 22Y & 23Y & 24Y & 25Y & 26Y & 27Y & 28Y & 29Y & 30Y \\
\hline
0\%  & 90.91  & 82.64  & 75.13  & 68.30  & 62.09  & 56.45  & 51.32  & 46.65  & 42.41  & 38.55  & 35.05  & 31.86  & 28.97  & 26.33  & 23.94  & 21.76  & 19.78  & 17.99  & 16.35  & 14.86  & 13.51  & 12.28  & 11.17  & 10.15  & 9.23   & 8.39   & 7.63   & 6.93   & 6.30   & 5.73   \\
1\%  & 91.82  & 84.38  & 77.62  & 71.47  & 65.88  & 60.80  & 56.18  & 51.99  & 48.17  & 44.70  & 41.54  & 38.68  & 36.07  & 33.70  & 31.55  & 29.59  & 27.81  & 26.19  & 24.72  & 23.38  & 22.16  & 21.06  & 20.05  & 19.14  & 18.31  & 17.55  & 16.86  & 16.24  & 15.67  & 15.16  \\
2\%  & 92.73  & 86.12  & 80.11  & 74.64  & 69.67  & 65.16  & 61.05  & 57.32  & 53.93  & 50.84  & 48.04  & 45.49  & 43.17  & 41.07  & 39.15  & 37.41  & 35.83  & 34.39  & 33.08  & 31.89  & 30.81  & 29.83  & 28.93  & 28.12  & 27.38  & 26.71  & 26.10  & 25.55  & 25.04  & 24.58  \\
3\%  & 93.64  & 87.85  & 82.59  & 77.81  & 73.46  & 69.51  & 65.92  & 62.66  & 59.69  & 56.99  & 54.53  & 52.30  & 50.28  & 48.43  & 46.76  & 45.23  & 43.85  & 42.59  & 41.45  & 40.41  & 39.46  & 38.60  & 37.82  & 37.11  & 36.46  & 35.87  & 35.34  & 34.85  & 34.41  & 34.01  \\
4\%  & 94.55  & 89.59  & 85.08  & 80.98  & 77.26  & 73.87  & 70.79  & 67.99  & 65.45  & 63.13  & 61.03  & 59.12  & 57.38  & 55.80  & 54.36  & 53.06  & 51.87  & 50.79  & 49.81  & 48.92  & 48.11  & 47.37  & 46.70  & 46.09  & 45.54  & 45.03  & 44.58  & 44.16  & 43.78  & 43.44  \\
5\%  & 95.45  & 91.32  & 87.57  & 84.15  & 81.05  & 78.22  & 75.66  & 73.33  & 71.20  & 69.28  & 67.52  & 65.93  & 64.48  & 63.17  & 61.97  & 60.88  & 59.89  & 58.99  & 58.18  & 57.43  & 56.76  & 56.14  & 55.58  & 55.08  & 54.61  & 54.20  & 53.81  & 53.47  & 53.15  & 52.87  \\
6\%  & 96.36  & 93.06  & 90.05  & 87.32  & 84.84  & 82.58  & 80.53  & 78.66  & 76.96  & 75.42  & 74.02  & 72.75  & 71.59  & 70.53  & 69.58  & 68.71  & 67.91  & 67.19  & 66.54  & 65.95  & 65.41  & 64.91  & 64.47  & 64.06  & 63.69  & 63.36  & 63.05  & 62.77  & 62.52  & 62.29  \\
7\%  & 97.27  & 94.79  & 92.54  & 90.49  & 88.63  & 86.93  & 85.39  & 84.00  & 82.72  & 81.57  & 80.51  & 79.56  & 78.69  & 77.90  & 77.18  & 76.53  & 75.94  & 75.40  & 74.91  & 74.46  & 74.05  & 73.69  & 73.35  & 73.05  & 72.77  & 72.52  & 72.29  & 72.08  & 71.89  & 71.72  \\
8\%  & 98.18  & 96.53  & 95.03  & 93.66  & 92.42  & 91.29  & 90.26  & 89.33  & 88.48  & 87.71  & 87.01  & 86.37  & 85.79  & 85.27  & 84.79  & 84.35  & 83.96  & 83.60  & 83.27  & 82.97  & 82.70  & 82.46  & 82.23  & 82.03  & 81.85  & 81.68  & 81.53  & 81.39  & 81.26  & 81.15  \\
9\%  & 99.09  & 98.26  & 97.51  & 96.83  & 96.21  & 95.64  & 95.13  & 94.67  & 94.24  & 93.86  & 93.50  & 93.19  & 92.90  & 92.63  & 92.39  & 92.18  & 91.98  & 91.80  & 91.64  & 91.49  & 91.35  & 91.23  & 91.12  & 91.02  & 90.92  & 90.84  & 90.76  & 90.69  & 90.63  & 90.57  \\
10\% & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 \\
11\% & 100.91 & 101.74 & 102.49 & 103.17 & 103.79 & 104.36 & 104.87 & 105.33 & 105.76 & 106.14 & 106.50 & 106.81 & 107.10 & 107.37 & 107.61 & 107.82 & 108.02 & 108.20 & 108.36 & 108.51 & 108.65 & 108.77 & 108.88 & 108.98 & 109.08 & 109.16 & 109.24 & 109.31 & 109.37 & 109.43 \\
12\% & 101.82 & 103.47 & 104.97 & 106.34 & 107.58 & 108.71 & 109.74 & 110.67 & 111.52 & 112.29 & 112.99 & 113.63 & 114.21 & 114.73 & 115.21 & 115.65 & 116.04 & 116.40 & 116.73 & 117.03 & 117.30 & 117.54 & 117.77 & 117.97 & 118.15 & 118.32 & 118.47 & 118.61 & 118.74 & 118.85 \\
13\% & 102.73 & 105.21 & 107.46 & 109.51 & 111.37 & 113.07 & 114.61 & 116.00 & 117.28 & 118.43 & 119.49 & 120.44 & 121.31 & 122.10 & 122.82 & 123.47 & 124.06 & 124.60 & 125.09 & 125.54 & 125.95 & 126.31 & 126.65 & 126.95 & 127.23 & 127.48 & 127.71 & 127.92 & 128.11 & 128.28 \\
14\% & 103.64 & 106.94 & 109.95 & 112.68 & 115.16 & 117.42 & 119.47 & 121.34 & 123.04 & 124.58 & 125.98 & 127.25 & 128.41 & 129.47 & 130.42 & 131.29 & 132.09 & 132.81 & 133.46 & 134.05 & 134.59 & 135.09 & 135.53 & 135.94 & 136.31 & 136.64 & 136.95 & 137.23 & 137.48 & 137.71 \\
15\% & 104.55 & 108.68 & 112.43 & 115.85 & 118.95 & 121.78 & 124.34 & 126.67 & 128.80 & 130.72 & 132.48 & 134.07 & 135.52 & 136.83 & 138.03 & 139.12 & 140.11 & 141.01 & 141.82 & 142.57 & 143.24 & 143.86 & 144.42 & 144.92 & 145.39 & 145.80 & 146.19 & 146.53 & 146.85 & 147.13 \\
16\% & 105.45 & 110.41 & 114.92 & 119.02 & 122.74 & 126.13 & 129.21 & 132.01 & 134.55 & 136.87 & 138.97 & 140.88 & 142.62 & 144.20 & 145.64 & 146.94 & 148.13 & 149.21 & 150.19 & 151.08 & 151.89 & 152.63 & 153.30 & 153.91 & 154.46 & 154.97 & 155.42 & 155.84 & 156.22 & 156.56 \\
17\% & 106.36 & 112.15 & 117.41 & 122.19 & 126.54 & 130.49 & 134.08 & 137.34 & 140.31 & 143.01 & 145.47 & 147.70 & 149.72 & 151.57 & 153.24 & 154.77 & 156.15 & 157.41 & 158.55 & 159.59 & 160.54 & 161.40 & 162.18 & 162.89 & 163.54 & 164.13 & 164.66 & 165.15 & 165.59 & 165.99 \\
18\% & 107.27 & 113.88 & 119.89 & 125.36 & 130.33 & 134.84 & 138.95 & 142.68 & 146.07 & 149.16 & 151.96 & 154.51 & 156.83 & 158.93 & 160.85 & 162.59 & 164.17 & 165.61 & 166.92 & 168.11 & 169.19 & 170.17 & 171.07 & 171.88 & 172.62 & 173.29 & 173.90 & 174.45 & 174.96 & 175.42 \\
19\% & 108.18 & 115.62 & 122.38 & 128.53 & 134.12 & 139.20 & 143.82 & 148.01 & 151.83 & 155.30 & 158.46 & 161.32 & 163.93 & 166.30 & 168.45 & 170.41 & 172.19 & 173.81 & 175.28 & 176.62 & 177.84 & 178.94 & 179.95 & 180.86 & 181.69 & 182.45 & 183.14 & 183.76 & 184.33 & 184.84 \\
20\% & 109.09 & 117.36 & 124.87 & 131.70 & 137.91 & 143.55 & 148.68 & 153.35 & 157.59 & 161.45 & 164.95 & 168.14 & 171.03 & 173.67 & 176.06 & 178.24 & 180.22 & 182.01 & 183.65 & 185.14 & 186.49 & 187.72 & 188.83 & 189.85 & 190.77 & 191.61 & 192.37 & 193.07 & 193.70 & 194.27 \\
\hline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that each `tabular` environment has 31 [!] columns, I see no way how they might be made to fit side-by-side on a page, unless you're willing to go with a microscopic font size and thereby assure that they'll be unreadable unless the reader happens to have a magnifying glass.

Even if one sets the font size to `\tiny`, for a 50% linear reduction from `\normalsize`, and sets the parameter `\tabcolsep` to `1.75pt` (default value: 6pt), one can barely make one `tabular` fit, assuming A4 for the paper size and margins of 2.5cm. Thus, the tables must be placed one above the other.

By the way, it's better to set the relative font size to `\tiny` than to employ the `\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{...}` method to make the table fit inside the textblock. By choosing `\tiny`, one gets glyphs that are optimized for readability at `5pt`; in contrast, the `\resizebox` approach will give you linearly-reduced normal-shaped glyphs, which aren't meant to be read at `5pt` sizes.

Oh, and since it would be appear to be important to align the numbers on their respective decimal markers, do use a package such as `dcolumn` to achieve this type of alignment, instead of the `c` alignment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rotating,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page size parameters

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}

\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{r}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\tiny
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.75pt} % default value: 6pt

\centering

\caption[test3]{test3}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{30}{d{3.2}} @{}} 
\toprule
YTM & \mc{1Y} & \mc{2Y} & \mc{3Y} & \mc{4Y} & \mc{5Y} & \mc{6Y} & \mc{7Y} & \mc{8Y} & \mc{9Y} & \mc{10Y} & \mc{11Y} & \mc{12Y} & \mc{13Y} & \mc{14Y} & \mc{15Y} & \mc{16Y} & \mc{17Y} & \mc{18Y} & \mc{18Y} & \mc{20Y} & \mc{21Y} & \mc{22Y} & \mc{23Y} & \mc{24Y} & \mc{25Y} & \mc{26Y} & \mc{27Y} & \mc{28Y} & \mc{29Y} & \mc{30Y} \\
\midrule
0\% & 110.00 & 120.00 & 130.00 & 140.00 & 150.00 & 160.00 & 170.00 & 180.00 & 190.00 & 200.00 & 210.00 & 220.00 & 230.00 & 240.00 & 250.00 & 260.00 & 270.00 & 280.00 & 290.00 & 300.00 & 310.00 & 320.00 & 330.00 & 340.00 & 350.00 & 360.00 & 370.00 & 380.00 & 390.00 & 400.00 \\
1\% & 108.91 & 117.73 & 126.47 & 135.12 & 143.68 & 152.16 & 160.55 & 168.87 & 177.09 & 185.24 & 193.31 & 201.30 & 209.20 & 217.03 & 224.79 & 232.46 & 240.06 & 247.58 & 255.03 & 262.41 & 269.71 & 276.94 & 284.10 & 291.19 & 298.21 & 305.16 & 312.04 & 318.85 & 325.59 & 332.27 \\
2\% & 107.84 & 115.53 & 123.07 & 130.46 & 137.71 & 144.81 & 151.78 & 158.60 & 165.30 & 171.86 & 178.29 & 184.60 & 190.79 & 196.85 & 202.79 & 208.62 & 214.33 & 219.94 & 225.43 & 230.81 & 236.09 & 241.26 & 246.34 & 251.31 & 256.19 & 260.97 & 265.66 & 270.25 & 274.76 & 279.17 \\
3\% & 106.80 & 113.39 & 119.80 & 126.02 & 132.06 & 137.92 & 143.61 & 149.14 & 154.50 & 159.71 & 164.77 & 169.68 & 174.44 & 179.07 & 183.57 & 187.93 & 192.16 & 196.27 & 200.27 & 204.14 & 207.91 & 211.56 & 215.11 & 218.55 & 221.89 & 225.14 & 228.29 & 231.35 & 234.32 & 237.20 \\
4\% & 105.77 & 111.32 & 116.65 & 121.78 & 126.71 & 131.45 & 136.01 & 140.40 & 144.61 & 148.67 & 152.56 & 156.31 & 159.91 & 163.38 & 166.71 & 169.91 & 172.99 & 175.96 & 178.80 & 181.54 & 184.17 & 186.71 & 189.14 & 191.48 & 193.73 & 195.90 & 197.98 & 199.98 & 201.90 & 203.75 \\
5\% & 104.76 & 109.30 & 113.62 & 117.73 & 121.65 & 125.38 & 128.93 & 132.32 & 135.54 & 138.61 & 141.53 & 144.32 & 146.97 & 149.49 & 151.90 & 154.19 & 156.37 & 158.45 & 160.43 & 162.31 & 164.11 & 165.82 & 167.44 & 168.99 & 170.47 & 171.88 & 173.22 & 174.49 & 175.71 & 176.86 \\
6\% & 103.77 & 107.33 & 110.69 & 113.86 & 116.85 & 119.67 & 122.33 & 124.84 & 127.21 & 129.44 & 131.55 & 133.54 & 135.41 & 137.18 & 138.85 & 140.42 & 141.91 & 143.31 & 144.63 & 145.88 & 147.06 & 148.17 & 149.21 & 150.20 & 151.13 & 152.01 & 152.84 & 153.62 & 154.36 & 155.06 \\
7\% & 102.80 & 105.42 & 107.87 & 110.16 & 112.30 & 114.30 & 116.17 & 117.91 & 119.55 & 121.07 & 122.50 & 123.83 & 125.07 & 126.24 & 127.32 & 128.34 & 129.29 & 130.18 & 131.01 & 131.78 & 132.51 & 133.18 & 133.82 & 134.41 & 134.96 & 135.48 & 135.96 & 136.41 & 136.83 & 137.23 \\
8\% & 101.85 & 103.57 & 105.15 & 106.62 & 107.99 & 109.25 & 110.41 & 111.49 & 112.49 & 113.42 & 114.28 & 115.07 & 115.81 & 116.49 & 117.12 & 117.70 & 118.24 & 118.74 & 119.21 & 119.64 & 120.03 & 120.40 & 120.74 & 121.06 & 121.35 & 121.62 & 121.87 & 122.10 & 122.32 & 122.52 \\
9\% & 100.92 & 101.76 & 102.53 & 103.24 & 103.89 & 104.49 & 105.03 & 105.53 & 106.00 & 106.42 & 106.81 & 107.16 & 107.49 & 107.79 & 108.06 & 108.31 & 108.54 & 108.76 & 108.95 & 109.13 & 109.29 & 109.44 & 109.58 & 109.71 & 109.82 & 109.93 & 110.03 & 110.12 & 110.20 & 110.27 \\
10\% & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 \\
11\% & 99.10 & 98.29 & 97.56 & 96.90 & 96.30 & 95.77 & 95.29 & 94.85 & 94.46 & 94.11 & 93.79 & 93.51 & 93.25 & 93.02 & 92.81 & 92.62 & 92.45 & 92.30 & 92.16 & 92.04 & 91.92 & 91.82 & 91.73 & 91.65 & 91.58 & 91.51 & 91.45 & 91.40 & 91.35 & 91.31 \\
12\% & 98.21 & 96.62 & 95.20 & 93.93 & 92.79 & 91.78 & 90.87 & 90.06 & 89.34 & 88.70 & 88.12 & 87.61 & 87.15 & 86.74 & 86.38 & 86.05 & 85.76 & 85.50 & 85.27 & 85.06 & 84.88 & 84.71 & 84.56 & 84.43 & 84.31 & 84.21 & 84.11 & 84.03 & 83.96 & 83.89 \\
13\% & 97.35 & 95.00 & 92.92 & 91.08 & 89.45 & 88.01 & 86.73 & 85.60 & 84.61 & 83.72 & 82.94 & 82.25 & 81.63 & 81.09 & 80.61 & 80.19 & 79.81 & 79.48 & 79.19 & 78.93 & 78.70 & 78.49 & 78.31 & 78.15 & 78.01 & 77.88 & 77.77 & 77.68 & 77.59 & 77.51 \\
14\% & 96.49 & 93.41 & 90.71 & 88.35 & 86.27 & 84.45 & 82.85 & 81.44 & 80.21 & 79.14 & 78.19 & 77.36 & 76.63 & 75.99 & 75.43 & 74.94 & 74.51 & 74.13 & 73.80 & 73.51 & 73.25 & 73.03 & 72.83 & 72.66 & 72.51 & 72.38 & 72.26 & 72.16 & 72.07 & 71.99 \\
15\% & 95.65 & 91.87 & 88.58 & 85.73 & 83.24 & 81.08 & 79.20 & 77.56 & 76.14 & 74.91 & 73.83 & 72.90 & 72.08 & 71.38 & 70.76 & 70.23 & 69.76 & 69.36 & 69.01 & 68.70 & 68.44 & 68.21 & 68.01 & 67.83 & 67.68 & 67.55 & 67.43 & 67.33 & 67.25 & 67.17 \\
16\% & 94.83 & 90.37 & 86.52 & 83.21 & 80.35 & 77.89 & 75.77 & 73.94 & 72.36 & 71.00 & 69.83 & 68.82 & 67.95 & 67.19 & 66.55 & 65.99 & 65.51 & 65.09 & 64.74 & 64.43 & 64.16 & 63.93 & 63.73 & 63.56 & 63.42 & 63.29 & 63.18 & 63.09 & 63.01 & 62.94 \\
17\% & 94.02 & 88.90 & 84.53 & 80.80 & 77.60 & 74.88 & 72.54 & 70.55 & 68.85 & 67.39 & 66.15 & 65.08 & 64.17 & 63.39 & 62.73 & 62.16 & 61.68 & 61.26 & 60.91 & 60.61 & 60.35 & 60.13 & 59.94 & 59.77 & 59.64 & 59.52 & 59.42 & 59.33 & 59.26 & 59.19 \\
18\% & 93.22 & 87.47 & 82.61 & 78.48 & 74.98 & 72.02 & 69.51 & 67.38 & 65.58 & 64.05 & 62.75 & 61.65 & 60.72 & 59.94 & 59.27 & 58.70 & 58.22 & 57.81 & 57.47 & 57.18 & 56.93 & 56.72 & 56.54 & 56.39 & 56.26 & 56.16 & 56.06 & 55.99 & 55.92 & 55.87 \\
19\% & 92.44 & 86.08 & 80.74 & 76.25 & 72.48 & 69.31 & 66.65 & 64.41 & 62.53 & 60.95 & 59.62 & 58.51 & 57.57 & 56.78 & 56.12 & 55.56 & 55.09 & 54.70 & 54.37 & 54.09 & 53.86 & 53.66 & 53.50 & 53.36 & 53.24 & 53.15 & 53.06 & 52.99 & 52.94 & 52.89 \\
20\% & 91.67 & 84.72 & 78.94 & 74.11 & 70.09 & 66.74 & 63.95 & 61.63 & 59.69 & 58.08 & 56.73 & 55.61 & 54.67 & 53.89 & 53.25 & 52.70 & 52.25 & 51.88 & 51.57 & 51.30 & 51.09 & 50.91 & 50.75 & 50.63 & 50.52 & 50.44 & 50.36 & 50.30 & 50.25 & 50.21\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\caption[test4]{test4}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{30}{d{3.2}} @{}} 
\toprule
YTM & \mc{1Y} & \mc{2Y} & \mc{3Y} & \mc{4Y} & \mc{5Y} & \mc{6Y} & \mc{7Y} & \mc{8Y} & \mc{9Y} & \mc{10Y} & \mc{11Y} & \mc{12Y} & \mc{13Y} & \mc{14Y} & \mc{15Y} & \mc{16Y} & \mc{17Y} & \mc{18Y} & \mc{18Y} & \mc{20Y} & \mc{21Y} & \mc{22Y} & \mc{23Y} & \mc{24Y} & \mc{25Y} & \mc{26Y} & \mc{27Y} & \mc{28Y} & \mc{29Y} & \mc{30Y} \\
\midrule
0\%  & 90.91  & 82.64  & 75.13  & 68.30  & 62.09  & 56.45  & 51.32  & 46.65  & 42.41  & 38.55  & 35.05  & 31.86  & 28.97  & 26.33  & 23.94  & 21.76  & 19.78  & 17.99  & 16.35  & 14.86  & 13.51  & 12.28  & 11.17  & 10.15  & 9.23   & 8.39   & 7.63   & 6.93   & 6.30   & 5.73   \\
1\%  & 91.82  & 84.38  & 77.62  & 71.47  & 65.88  & 60.80  & 56.18  & 51.99  & 48.17  & 44.70  & 41.54  & 38.68  & 36.07  & 33.70  & 31.55  & 29.59  & 27.81  & 26.19  & 24.72  & 23.38  & 22.16  & 21.06  & 20.05  & 19.14  & 18.31  & 17.55  & 16.86  & 16.24  & 15.67  & 15.16  \\
2\%  & 92.73  & 86.12  & 80.11  & 74.64  & 69.67  & 65.16  & 61.05  & 57.32  & 53.93  & 50.84  & 48.04  & 45.49  & 43.17  & 41.07  & 39.15  & 37.41  & 35.83  & 34.39  & 33.08  & 31.89  & 30.81  & 29.83  & 28.93  & 28.12  & 27.38  & 26.71  & 26.10  & 25.55  & 25.04  & 24.58  \\
3\%  & 93.64  & 87.85  & 82.59  & 77.81  & 73.46  & 69.51  & 65.92  & 62.66  & 59.69  & 56.99  & 54.53  & 52.30  & 50.28  & 48.43  & 46.76  & 45.23  & 43.85  & 42.59  & 41.45  & 40.41  & 39.46  & 38.60  & 37.82  & 37.11  & 36.46  & 35.87  & 35.34  & 34.85  & 34.41  & 34.01  \\
4\%  & 94.55  & 89.59  & 85.08  & 80.98  & 77.26  & 73.87  & 70.79  & 67.99  & 65.45  & 63.13  & 61.03  & 59.12  & 57.38  & 55.80  & 54.36  & 53.06  & 51.87  & 50.79  & 49.81  & 48.92  & 48.11  & 47.37  & 46.70  & 46.09  & 45.54  & 45.03  & 44.58  & 44.16  & 43.78  & 43.44  \\
5\%  & 95.45  & 91.32  & 87.57  & 84.15  & 81.05  & 78.22  & 75.66  & 73.33  & 71.20  & 69.28  & 67.52  & 65.93  & 64.48  & 63.17  & 61.97  & 60.88  & 59.89  & 58.99  & 58.18  & 57.43  & 56.76  & 56.14  & 55.58  & 55.08  & 54.61  & 54.20  & 53.81  & 53.47  & 53.15  & 52.87  \\
6\%  & 96.36  & 93.06  & 90.05  & 87.32  & 84.84  & 82.58  & 80.53  & 78.66  & 76.96  & 75.42  & 74.02  & 72.75  & 71.59  & 70.53  & 69.58  & 68.71  & 67.91  & 67.19  & 66.54  & 65.95  & 65.41  & 64.91  & 64.47  & 64.06  & 63.69  & 63.36  & 63.05  & 62.77  & 62.52  & 62.29  \\
7\%  & 97.27  & 94.79  & 92.54  & 90.49  & 88.63  & 86.93  & 85.39  & 84.00  & 82.72  & 81.57  & 80.51  & 79.56  & 78.69  & 77.90  & 77.18  & 76.53  & 75.94  & 75.40  & 74.91  & 74.46  & 74.05  & 73.69  & 73.35  & 73.05  & 72.77  & 72.52  & 72.29  & 72.08  & 71.89  & 71.72  \\
8\%  & 98.18  & 96.53  & 95.03  & 93.66  & 92.42  & 91.29  & 90.26  & 89.33  & 88.48  & 87.71  & 87.01  & 86.37  & 85.79  & 85.27  & 84.79  & 84.35  & 83.96  & 83.60  & 83.27  & 82.97  & 82.70  & 82.46  & 82.23  & 82.03  & 81.85  & 81.68  & 81.53  & 81.39  & 81.26  & 81.15  \\
9\%  & 99.09  & 98.26  & 97.51  & 96.83  & 96.21  & 95.64  & 95.13  & 94.67  & 94.24  & 93.86  & 93.50  & 93.19  & 92.90  & 92.63  & 92.39  & 92.18  & 91.98  & 91.80  & 91.64  & 91.49  & 91.35  & 91.23  & 91.12  & 91.02  & 90.92  & 90.84  & 90.76  & 90.69  & 90.63  & 90.57  \\
10\% & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 \\
11\% & 100.91 & 101.74 & 102.49 & 103.17 & 103.79 & 104.36 & 104.87 & 105.33 & 105.76 & 106.14 & 106.50 & 106.81 & 107.10 & 107.37 & 107.61 & 107.82 & 108.02 & 108.20 & 108.36 & 108.51 & 108.65 & 108.77 & 108.88 & 108.98 & 109.08 & 109.16 & 109.24 & 109.31 & 109.37 & 109.43 \\
12\% & 101.82 & 103.47 & 104.97 & 106.34 & 107.58 & 108.71 & 109.74 & 110.67 & 111.52 & 112.29 & 112.99 & 113.63 & 114.21 & 114.73 & 115.21 & 115.65 & 116.04 & 116.40 & 116.73 & 117.03 & 117.30 & 117.54 & 117.77 & 117.97 & 118.15 & 118.32 & 118.47 & 118.61 & 118.74 & 118.85 \\
13\% & 102.73 & 105.21 & 107.46 & 109.51 & 111.37 & 113.07 & 114.61 & 116.00 & 117.28 & 118.43 & 119.49 & 120.44 & 121.31 & 122.10 & 122.82 & 123.47 & 124.06 & 124.60 & 125.09 & 125.54 & 125.95 & 126.31 & 126.65 & 126.95 & 127.23 & 127.48 & 127.71 & 127.92 & 128.11 & 128.28 \\
14\% & 103.64 & 106.94 & 109.95 & 112.68 & 115.16 & 117.42 & 119.47 & 121.34 & 123.04 & 124.58 & 125.98 & 127.25 & 128.41 & 129.47 & 130.42 & 131.29 & 132.09 & 132.81 & 133.46 & 134.05 & 134.59 & 135.09 & 135.53 & 135.94 & 136.31 & 136.64 & 136.95 & 137.23 & 137.48 & 137.71 \\
15\% & 104.55 & 108.68 & 112.43 & 115.85 & 118.95 & 121.78 & 124.34 & 126.67 & 128.80 & 130.72 & 132.48 & 134.07 & 135.52 & 136.83 & 138.03 & 139.12 & 140.11 & 141.01 & 141.82 & 142.57 & 143.24 & 143.86 & 144.42 & 144.92 & 145.39 & 145.80 & 146.19 & 146.53 & 146.85 & 147.13 \\
16\% & 105.45 & 110.41 & 114.92 & 119.02 & 122.74 & 126.13 & 129.21 & 132.01 & 134.55 & 136.87 & 138.97 & 140.88 & 142.62 & 144.20 & 145.64 & 146.94 & 148.13 & 149.21 & 150.19 & 151.08 & 151.89 & 152.63 & 153.30 & 153.91 & 154.46 & 154.97 & 155.42 & 155.84 & 156.22 & 156.56 \\
17\% & 106.36 & 112.15 & 117.41 & 122.19 & 126.54 & 130.49 & 134.08 & 137.34 & 140.31 & 143.01 & 145.47 & 147.70 & 149.72 & 151.57 & 153.24 & 154.77 & 156.15 & 157.41 & 158.55 & 159.59 & 160.54 & 161.40 & 162.18 & 162.89 & 163.54 & 164.13 & 164.66 & 165.15 & 165.59 & 165.99 \\
18\% & 107.27 & 113.88 & 119.89 & 125.36 & 130.33 & 134.84 & 138.95 & 142.68 & 146.07 & 149.16 & 151.96 & 154.51 & 156.83 & 158.93 & 160.85 & 162.59 & 164.17 & 165.61 & 166.92 & 168.11 & 169.19 & 170.17 & 171.07 & 171.88 & 172.62 & 173.29 & 173.90 & 174.45 & 174.96 & 175.42 \\
19\% & 108.18 & 115.62 & 122.38 & 128.53 & 134.12 & 139.20 & 143.82 & 148.01 & 151.83 & 155.30 & 158.46 & 161.32 & 163.93 & 166.30 & 168.45 & 170.41 & 172.19 & 173.81 & 175.28 & 176.62 & 177.84 & 178.94 & 179.95 & 180.86 & 181.69 & 182.45 & 183.14 & 183.76 & 184.33 & 184.84 \\
20\% & 109.09 & 117.36 & 124.87 & 131.70 & 137.91 & 143.55 & 148.68 & 153.35 & 157.59 & 161.45 & 164.95 & 168.14 & 171.03 & 173.67 & 176.06 & 178.24 & 180.22 & 182.01 & 183.65 & 185.14 & 186.49 & 187.72 & 188.83 & 189.85 & 190.77 & 191.61 & 192.37 & 193.07 & 193.70 & 194.27 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
Since my suggestion, how to improve looks of both tables, if you employ `S` column column type from `siunitx` package, I decided to rewrite my answer following my estimation, that two so huge table squeezed in one page, even in landscape orientation, is not readable in such haven't sense to be present in document. So, I suggest (and encourage you) to split tables into two parts, all parts transpose and then present each adjacent pairs onto own pages. In this right (powerful) tool is `pgfplotstable` package.

For employing `pgfplotstable` I do the following:

- existed table I use as content of `\pgfplotstableread{...}\tableA` (for the first table) and  `\pgfplotstableread{...}\tableB` (for the second table}
- by help of editor replace all ampersands, `\\` and `\%` with empty spaces
- in `\pgfplotstabletypeset[ ... ]` determine table layout
- by `\pgfplotstabletranspose[ ... ]` transpose table, i.e. rows convert into columns and \columns into rows. By the the table become significantly shorter and with this enable, that in landscape`oriented page can be used font size`\small`
- with macro `skip rows between index={0}{15}` and `skip rows between index={15}{30}` split tables into two parts
- with macro `every nth row = {3}{before row=\addlinespace}` introduce small vertical space after each third row and with this make table more easy to read.

Complete code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage[font={small,sf},
                labelfont=bf,
                skip=0pt]{caption}
    \usepackage[strict]{changepage}
    \usepackage[margin=25mm,showframe]{geometry}

    \begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%    
\pgfplotstableread{
exp. 1Y 2Y 3Y 4Y 5Y 6Y 7Y 8Y 9Y 10Y 11Y 12Y 13Y 14Y 15Y 16Y 17Y 18Y 19Y 20Y 21Y 22Y 23Y 24Y 25Y 26Y 27Y 28Y 29Y 30Y
0  90.91 82.64 75.13 68.30 62.09 56.45 51.32 46.65 42.41 38.55 35.05 31.86 28.97 26.33 23.94 21.76 19.78 17.99 16.35 14.86 13.51 12.28 11.17 10.15 9.23 8.39 7.63 6.93 6.30 5.73
1  91.82 84.38 77.62 71.47 65.88 60.80 56.18 51.99 48.17 44.70 41.54 38.68 36.07 33.70 31.55 29.59 27.81 26.19 24.72 23.38 22.16 21.06 20.05 19.14 18.31 17.55 16.86 16.24 15.67 15.16
2  92.73 86.12 80.11 74.64 69.67 65.16 61.05 57.32 53.93 50.84 48.04 45.49 43.17 41.07 39.15 37.41 35.83 34.39 33.08 31.89 30.81 29.83 28.93 28.12 27.38 26.71 26.10 25.55 25.04 24.58
3  93.64 87.85 82.59 77.81 73.46 69.51 65.92 62.66 59.69 56.99 54.53 52.30 50.28 48.43 46.76 45.23 43.85 42.59 41.45 40.41 39.46 38.60 37.82 37.11 36.46 35.87 35.34 34.85 34.41 34.01
4  94.55 89.59 85.08 80.98 77.26 73.87 70.79 67.99 65.45 63.13 61.03 59.12 57.38 55.80 54.36 53.06 51.87 50.79 49.81 48.92 48.11 47.37 46.70 46.09 45.54 45.03 44.58 44.16 43.78 43.44
5  95.45 91.32 87.57 84.15 81.05 78.22 75.66 73.33 71.20 69.28 67.52 65.93 64.48 63.17 61.97 60.88 59.89 58.99 58.18 57.43 56.76 56.14 55.58 55.08 54.61 54.20 53.81 53.47 53.15 52.87
6  96.36 93.06 90.05 87.32 84.84 82.58 80.53 78.66 76.96 75.42 74.02 72.75 71.59 70.53 69.58 68.71 67.91 67.19 66.54 65.95 65.41 64.91 64.47 64.06 63.69 63.36 63.05 62.77 62.52 62.29
7  97.27 94.79 92.54 90.49 88.63 86.93 85.39 84   82.72 81.57 80.51 79.56 78.69 77.90 77.18 76.53 75.94 75.40 74.91 74.46 74.05 73.69 73.35 73.05 72.77 72.52 72.29 72.08 71.89 71.72
8  98.18 96.53 95.03 93.66 92.42 91.29 90.26 89.33 88.48 87.71 87.01 86.37 85.79 85.27 84.79 84.35 83.96 83.60 83.27 82.97 82.70 82.46 82.23 82.03 81.85 81.68 81.53 81.39 81.26 81.15
9  99.09 98.26 97.51 96.83 96.21 95.64 95.13 94.67 94.24 93.86 93.50 93.19 92.90 92.63 92.39 92.18 91.98 91.80 91.64 91.49 91.35 91.23 91.12 91.02 90.92 90.84 90.76 90.69 90.63 90.57
10  100 100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100 
11  100.91 101.74 102.49 103.17 103.79 104.36 104.87 105.33 105.76 106.14 106.50 106.81 107.10 107.37 107.61 107.82 108.02 108.20 108.36 108.51 108.65 108.77 108.88 108.98 109.08 109.16 109.24 109.31 109.37 109.43
12  101.82 103.47 104.97 106.34 107.58 108.71 109.74 110.67 111.52 112.29 112.99 113.63 114.21 114.73 115.21 115.65 116.04 116.40 116.73 117.03 117.30 117.54 117.77 117.97 118.15 118.32 118.47 118.61 118.74 118.85
13  102.73 105.21 107.46 109.51 111.37 113.07 114.61 116   117.28 118.43 119.49 120.44 121.31 122.10 122.82 123.47 124.06 124.60 125.09 125.54 125.95 126.31 126.65 126.95 127.23 127.48 127.71 127.92 128.11 128.28
14  103.64 106.94 109.95 112.68 115.16 117.42 119.47 121.34 123.04 124.58 125.98 127.25 128.41 129.47 130.42 131.29 132.09 132.81 133.46 134.05 134.59 135.09 135.53 135.94 136.31 136.64 136.95 137.23 137.48 137.71
15  104.55 108.68 112.43 115.85 118.95 121.78 124.34 126.67 128.80 130.72 132.48 134.07 135.52 136.83 138.03 139.12 140.11 141.01 141.82 142.57 143.24 143.86 144.42 144.92 145.39 145.80 146.19 146.53 146.85 147.13
16  105.45 110.41 114.92 119.02 122.74 126.13 129.21 132.01 134.55 136.87 138.97 140.88 142.62 144.20 145.64 146.94 148.13 149.21 150.19 151.08 151.89 152.63 153.30 153.91 154.46 154.97 155.42 155.84 156.22 156.56
17  106.36 112.15 117.41 122.19 126.54 130.49 134.08 137.34 140.31 143.01 145.47 147.70 149.72 151.57 153.24 154.77 156.15 157.41 158.55 159.59 160.54 161.40 162.18 162.89 163.54 164.13 164.66 165.15 165.59 165.99
18  107.27 113.88 119.89 125.36 130.33 134.84 138.95 142.68 146.07 149.16 151.96 154.51 156.83 158.93 160.85 162.59 164.17 165.61 166.92 168.11 169.19 170.17 171.07 171.88 172.62 173.29 173.90 174.45 174.96 175.42
19  108.18 115.62 122.38 128.53 134.12 139.20 143.82 148.01 151.83 155.30 158.46 161.32 163.93 166.30 168.45 170.41 172.19 173.81 175.28 176.62 177.84 178.94 179.95 180.86 181.69 182.45 183.14 183.76 184.33 184.84
20  109.09 117.36 124.87 131.70 137.91 143.55 148.68 153.35 157.59 161.45 164.95 168.14 171.03 173.67 176.06 178.24 180.22 182.01 183.65 185.14 186.49 187.72 188.83 189.85 190.77 191.61 192.37 193.07 193.70 194.27
}\tableA
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\pgfplotstableread{
exp. 1Y 2Y 3Y 4Y 5Y 6Y 7Y 8Y 9Y 10Y 11Y 12Y 13Y 14Y 15Y 16Y 17Y 18Y 19Y 20Y 21Y 22Y 23Y 24Y 25Y 26Y 27Y 28Y 29Y 30Y
0      110   120   130   140   150   160   170   180   190   200   210   220   230   240   250   260   270   280   290   300   310   320   330   340   350   360   370   380   390   400
1      108.91   117.73   126.47   135.12   143.68   152.16   160.55   168.87   177.09   185.24   193.31   201.30   209.20   217.03   224.79   232.46   240.06   247.58   255.03   262.41   269.71   276.94   284.10   291.19   298.21   305.16   312.04   318.85   325.59   332.27
2      107.84   115.53   123.07   130.46   137.71   144.81   151.78   158.60   165.30   171.86   178.29   184.60   190.79   196.85   202.79   208.62   214.33   219.94   225.43   230.81   236.09   241.26   246.34   251.31   256.19   260.97   265.66   270.25   274.76   279.17
3      106.80   113.39   119.80   126.02   132.06   137.92   143.61   149.14   154.50   159.71   164.77   169.68   174.44   179.07   183.57   187.93   192.16   196.27   200.27   204.14   207.91   211.56   215.11   218.55   221.89   225.14   228.29   231.35   234.32   237.20
4      105.77   111.32   116.65   121.78   126.71   131.45   136.01   140.40   144.61   148.67   152.56   156.31   159.91   163.38   166.71   169.91   172.99   175.96   178.80   181.54   184.17   186.71   189.14   191.48   193.73   195.90   197.98   199.98   201.90   203.75
5      104.76   109.30   113.62   117.73   121.65   125.38   128.93   132.32   135.54   138.61   141.53   144.32   146.97   149.49   151.90   154.19   156.37   158.45   160.43   162.31   164.11   165.82   167.44   168.99   170.47   171.88   173.22   174.49   175.71   176.86
6      103.77   107.33   110.69   113.86   116.85   119.67   122.33   124.84   127.21   129.44   131.55   133.54   135.41   137.18   138.85   140.42   141.91   143.31   144.63   145.88   147.06   148.17   149.21   150.20   151.13   152.01   152.84   153.62   154.36   155.06
7      102.80   105.42   107.87   110.16   112.30   114.30   116.17   117.91   119.55   121.07   122.50   123.83   125.07   126.24   127.32   128.34   129.29   130.18   131.01   131.78   132.51   133.18   133.82   134.41   134.96   135.48   135.96   136.41   136.83   137.23
8      101.85   103.57   105.15   106.62   107.99   109.25   110.41   111.49   112.49   113.42   114.28   115.07   115.81   116.49   117.12   117.70   118.24   118.74   119.21   119.64   120.03   120.40   120.74   121.06   121.35   121.62   121.87   122.10   122.32   122.52
9      100.92   101.76   102.53   103.24   103.89   104.49   105.03   105.53   106   106.42   106.81   107.16   107.49   107.79   108.06   108.31   108.54   108.76   108.95   109.13   109.29   109.44   109.58   109.71   109.82   109.93   110.03   110.12   110.20   110.27
10      100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100
11      99.10   98.29   97.56   96.90   96.30   95.77   95.29   94.85   94.46   94.11   93.79   93.51   93.25   93.02   92.81   92.62   92.45   92.30   92.16   92.04   91.92   91.82   91.73   91.65   91.58   91.51   91.45   91.40   91.35   91.31
12      98.21   96.62   95.20   93.93   92.79   91.78   90.87   90.06   89.34   88.70   88.12   87.61   87.15   86.74   86.38   86.05   85.76   85.50   85.27   85.06   84.88   84.71   84.56   84.43   84.31   84.21   84.11   84.03   83.96   83.89
13      97.35   95   92.92   91.08   89.45   88.01   86.73   85.60   84.61   83.72   82.94   82.25   81.63   81.09   80.61   80.19   79.81   79.48   79.19   78.93   78.70   78.49   78.31   78.15   78.01   77.88   77.77   77.68   77.59   77.51
14      96.49   93.41   90.71   88.35   86.27   84.45   82.85   81.44   80.21   79.14   78.19   77.36   76.63   75.99   75.43   74.94   74.51   74.13   73.80   73.51   73.25   73.03   72.83   72.66   72.51   72.38   72.26   72.16   72.07   71.99
15      95.65   91.87   88.58   85.73   83.24   81.08   79.20   77.56   76.14   74.91   73.83   72.90   72.08   71.38   70.76   70.23   69.76   69.36   69.01   68.70   68.44   68.21   68.01   67.83   67.68   67.55   67.43   67.33   67.25   67.17
16      94.83   90.37   86.52   83.21   80.35   77.89   75.77   73.94   72.36   71   69.83   68.82   67.95   67.19   66.55   65.99   65.51   65.09   64.74   64.43   64.16   63.93   63.73   63.56   63.42   63.29   63.18   63.09   63.01   62.94
17      94.02   88.90   84.53   80.80   77.60   74.88   72.54   70.55   68.85   67.39   66.15   65.08   64.17   63.39   62.73   62.16   61.68   61.26   60.91   60.61   60.35   60.13   59.94   59.77   59.64   59.52   59.42   59.33   59.26   59.19
18      93.22   87.47   82.61   78.48   74.98   72.02   69.51   67.38   65.58   64.05   62.75   61.65   60.72   59.94   59.27   58.70   58.22   57.81   57.47   57.18   56.93   56.72   56.54   56.39   56.26   56.16   56.06   55.99   55.92   55.87
19      92.44   86.08   80.74   76.25   72.48   69.31   66.65   64.41   62.53   60.95   59.62   58.51   57.57   56.78   56.12   55.56   55.09   54.70   54.37   54.09   53.86   53.66   53.50   53.36   53.24   53.15   53.06   52.99   52.94   52.89
20      91.67   84.72   78.94   74.11   70.09   66.74   63.95   61.63   59.69   58.08   56.73   55.61   54.67   53.89   53.25   52.70   52.25   51.88   51.57   51.30   51.09   50.91   50.75   50.63   50.52   50.44   50.36   50.30   50.25   50.21   
}\tableB
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\pgfplotstabletranspose[string type,
                        colnames from=exp.,
                        input colnames to=exp.
                        ]\talltableA{\tableA}
\pgfplotstabletranspose[string type,
                        colnames from=exp.,
                        input colnames to=exp.
                        ]\talltableB{\tableB}

\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.4pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.9}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \caption{Test.}
    \label{tab:table-results-1}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,
            every nth row = {3}{before row=\addlinespace},
    every head row/.style = {output empty row,
                             before row={\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-22}
                                \multicolumn{20}{c}{YMT (in \%)}\\
                                \cmidrule(lr){2-22}
   exp. & \SI{0}{\%} & \SI{1}{\%} & \SI{2}{\%} & \SI{3}{\%} & \SI{4}{\%}
        & \SI{5}{\%} & \SI{6}{\%} & \SI{7}{\%} & \SI{8}{\%} & \SI{9}{\%}
        &\SI{10}{\%} &\SI{11}{\%} &\SI{12}{\%} &\SI{13}{\%} &\SI{14}{\%}
        &\SI{15}{\%} &\SI{16}{\%} &\SI{17}{\%} &\SI{18}{\%} &\SI{19}{\%}
        &\SI{20}{\%}                                            \\
                                         },
                             after row=\midrule,
                            },
    every last row/.style = {after row=\bottomrule},
%
    skip rows between index={15}{30},
%
 every even column/.style = {column type={S[table-format=3.2]}},
 every  odd column/.style = {column type={S[table-format=3.2]}},
display columns/11/.style = {column type={S[table-format=3.0,
                                            table-number-alignment=center]}},
      columns/exp./.style = {column type=r},
                        ]{\talltableA}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\vspace{2\baselineskip}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \caption{Test.}
    \label{tab:table-results-2}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,
            every nth row = {3}{before row=\addlinespace},
    every head row/.style = {output empty row,
                             before row={\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-22}
                                \multicolumn{20}{c}{YMT (in \%)}\\
                                \cmidrule(lr){2-22}
   exp. & \SI{0}{\%} & \SI{1}{\%} & \SI{2}{\%} & \SI{3}{\%} & \SI{4}{\%}
        & \SI{5}{\%} & \SI{6}{\%} & \SI{7}{\%} & \SI{8}{\%} & \SI{9}{\%}
        &\SI{10}{\%} &\SI{11}{\%} &\SI{12}{\%} &\SI{13}{\%} &\SI{14}{\%}
        &\SI{15}{\%} &\SI{16}{\%} &\SI{17}{\%} &\SI{18}{\%} &\SI{19}{\%}
        &\SI{20}{\%}                                            \\
                                         },
                             after row=\midrule,
                            },
    every last row/.style = {after row=\bottomrule},
%
    skip rows between index={15}{30},
%
 every even column/.style = {column type={S[table-format=3.2]}},
 every  odd column/.style = {column type={S[table-format=3.2]}},
display columns/11/.style = {column type={S[table-format=3.0,
                                            table-number-alignment=center]}},
display columns/1/.style = {column type={S[table-format=4.1,
                                            table-number-alignment=center]}},
      columns/exp./.style = {column type=r},
                        ]{\talltableB}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\end{sidewaystable}

\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.4pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.9}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \caption{Test (cont. of Table \ref{tab:table-results-1}).}
    \label{tab:table-results-3}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,
            every nth row = {3}{before row=\addlinespace},
    every head row/.style = {output empty row,
                             before row={\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-22}
                                \multicolumn{20}{c}{YMT (in \%)}\\
                                \cmidrule(lr){2-22}
   exp. & \SI{0}{\%} & \SI{1}{\%} & \SI{2}{\%} & \SI{3}{\%} & \SI{4}{\%}
        & \SI{5}{\%} & \SI{6}{\%} & \SI{7}{\%} & \SI{8}{\%} & \SI{9}{\%}
        &\SI{10}{\%} &\SI{11}{\%} &\SI{12}{\%} &\SI{13}{\%} &\SI{14}{\%}
        &\SI{15}{\%} &\SI{16}{\%} &\SI{17}{\%} &\SI{18}{\%} &\SI{19}{\%}
        &\SI{20}{\%}                                            \\
                                         },
                             after row=\midrule,
                            },
    every last row/.style = {after row=\bottomrule},
%
    skip rows between index={0}{15},
%
 every even column/.style = {column type={S[table-format=3.2]}},
 every  odd column/.style = {column type={S[table-format=3.2]}},
display columns/11/.style = {column type={S[table-format=3.0,
                                            table-number-alignment=center]}},
      columns/exp./.style = {column type=r},
                        ]{\talltableA}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\vspace{2\baselineskip}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \caption{Test (cont. of Table \ref{tab:table-results-2}).}
    \label{tab:table-results-4}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,
            every nth row = {3}{before row=\addlinespace},
    every head row/.style = {output empty row,
                             before row={\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-22}
                                \multicolumn{20}{c}{YMT (in \%)}\\
                                \cmidrule(lr){2-22}
   exp. & \SI{0}{\%} & \SI{1}{\%} & \SI{2}{\%} & \SI{3}{\%} & \SI{4}{\%}
        & \SI{5}{\%} & \SI{6}{\%} & \SI{7}{\%} & \SI{8}{\%} & \SI{9}{\%}
        &\SI{10}{\%} &\SI{11}{\%} &\SI{12}{\%} &\SI{13}{\%} &\SI{14}{\%}
        &\SI{15}{\%} &\SI{16}{\%} &\SI{17}{\%} &\SI{18}{\%} &\SI{19}{\%}
        &\SI{20}{\%}                                            \\
                                         },
                             after row=\midrule,
                            },
    every last row/.style = {after row=\bottomrule},
%
    skip rows between index={0}{15},
%
 every even column/.style = {column type={S[table-format=3.2]}},
 every  odd column/.style = {column type={S[table-format=3.2]}},
display columns/11/.style = {column type={S[table-format=3.0,
                                            table-number-alignment=center]}},
display columns/1/.style = {column type={S[table-format=4.1,
                                            table-number-alignment=center]}},
      columns/exp./.style = {column type=r},
                        ]{\talltableB}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\end{sidewaystable}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \end{document}
```

Result: shown is only second page with second parts of both tables (the first page is similar):

[image]

I'm convinced, that only such (on two or more pages) presentation of your tables have sense. Enable easy reading of contents of table, comparisons of results, ... and not at last, typographical are more acceptable as on one page squeezed  solutions with font sizes smaller as `tiny`.

Comment: The best thanks from you is if you vote answer. :-). Meanwhile I prepare one far more readable solution, however, as I see, you already select one of among provided, so it is no need anymore to publish  it here

Comment: @SilvanoMarchesi, I change the mind and after all decided to publish here one (to me very attractive) solution of your problem. So I rewrote my answer. If you have time, see it.

Comment: +1. I like your idea of giving more structure to the header. Shouldn't the acronym be YTM (yield to maturity), though?

Comment: I really like your solution too, zarko! But since it is my bachelor thesis and i already got 60 pages i need to keep it short regarding the number of pages in the appendix. These tables just need to justify my graphics, so i prefer to keep them on one page.

@Mico, yes, YTM stands for Yield to Maturity. These tables show bond prices under variation of YTM and Time to Maturity.

Answer (score 1):

Your code (minipages with half width, btw. you should not use 0.5 twice as this assumes ideal flawless calculation) seems to imply you want the two tables to be side by side? To be frank: thats not going to happen.  If I were you I would transpose the tables and even then you probably would have to use longtable, because they are *huge*.

If however you insist on this format, the only remaining is solution is to make the font smaller. So you could say something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\caption[test3]{test3}
\centering
\tiny
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc} \toprule
\hline\hline
YTM & 1Y & 2Y & 3Y & 4Y & 5Y & 6Y & 7Y & 8Y & 9Y & 10Y & 11Y & 12Y & 13Y & 14Y & 15Y & 16Y & 17Y & 18Y & 18Y & 20Y & 21Y & 22Y & 23Y & 24Y & 25Y & 26Y & 27Y & 28Y & 29Y & 30Y \\
\hline
0\% & 110.00 & 120.00 & 130.00 & 140.00 & 150.00 & 160.00 & 170.00 & 180.00 & 190.00 & 200.00 & 210.00 & 220.00 & 230.00 & 240.00 & 250.00 & 260.00 & 270.00 & 280.00 & 290.00 & 300.00 & 310.00 & 320.00 & 330.00 & 340.00 & 350.00 & 360.00 & 370.00 & 380.00 & 390.00 & 400.00 \\
1\% & 108.91 & 117.73 & 126.47 & 135.12 & 143.68 & 152.16 & 160.55 & 168.87 & 177.09 & 185.24 & 193.31 & 201.30 & 209.20 & 217.03 & 224.79 & 232.46 & 240.06 & 247.58 & 255.03 & 262.41 & 269.71 & 276.94 & 284.10 & 291.19 & 298.21 & 305.16 & 312.04 & 318.85 & 325.59 & 332.27 \\
2\% & 107.84 & 115.53 & 123.07 & 130.46 & 137.71 & 144.81 & 151.78 & 158.60 & 165.30 & 171.86 & 178.29 & 184.60 & 190.79 & 196.85 & 202.79 & 208.62 & 214.33 & 219.94 & 225.43 & 230.81 & 236.09 & 241.26 & 246.34 & 251.31 & 256.19 & 260.97 & 265.66 & 270.25 & 274.76 & 279.17 \\
3\% & 106.80 & 113.39 & 119.80 & 126.02 & 132.06 & 137.92 & 143.61 & 149.14 & 154.50 & 159.71 & 164.77 & 169.68 & 174.44 & 179.07 & 183.57 & 187.93 & 192.16 & 196.27 & 200.27 & 204.14 & 207.91 & 211.56 & 215.11 & 218.55 & 221.89 & 225.14 & 228.29 & 231.35 & 234.32 & 237.20 \\
4\% & 105.77 & 111.32 & 116.65 & 121.78 & 126.71 & 131.45 & 136.01 & 140.40 & 144.61 & 148.67 & 152.56 & 156.31 & 159.91 & 163.38 & 166.71 & 169.91 & 172.99 & 175.96 & 178.80 & 181.54 & 184.17 & 186.71 & 189.14 & 191.48 & 193.73 & 195.90 & 197.98 & 199.98 & 201.90 & 203.75 \\
5\% & 104.76 & 109.30 & 113.62 & 117.73 & 121.65 & 125.38 & 128.93 & 132.32 & 135.54 & 138.61 & 141.53 & 144.32 & 146.97 & 149.49 & 151.90 & 154.19 & 156.37 & 158.45 & 160.43 & 162.31 & 164.11 & 165.82 & 167.44 & 168.99 & 170.47 & 171.88 & 173.22 & 174.49 & 175.71 & 176.86 \\
6\% & 103.77 & 107.33 & 110.69 & 113.86 & 116.85 & 119.67 & 122.33 & 124.84 & 127.21 & 129.44 & 131.55 & 133.54 & 135.41 & 137.18 & 138.85 & 140.42 & 141.91 & 143.31 & 144.63 & 145.88 & 147.06 & 148.17 & 149.21 & 150.20 & 151.13 & 152.01 & 152.84 & 153.62 & 154.36 & 155.06 \\
7\% & 102.80 & 105.42 & 107.87 & 110.16 & 112.30 & 114.30 & 116.17 & 117.91 & 119.55 & 121.07 & 122.50 & 123.83 & 125.07 & 126.24 & 127.32 & 128.34 & 129.29 & 130.18 & 131.01 & 131.78 & 132.51 & 133.18 & 133.82 & 134.41 & 134.96 & 135.48 & 135.96 & 136.41 & 136.83 & 137.23 \\
8\% & 101.85 & 103.57 & 105.15 & 106.62 & 107.99 & 109.25 & 110.41 & 111.49 & 112.49 & 113.42 & 114.28 & 115.07 & 115.81 & 116.49 & 117.12 & 117.70 & 118.24 & 118.74 & 119.21 & 119.64 & 120.03 & 120.40 & 120.74 & 121.06 & 121.35 & 121.62 & 121.87 & 122.10 & 122.32 & 122.52 \\
9\% & 100.92 & 101.76 & 102.53 & 103.24 & 103.89 & 104.49 & 105.03 & 105.53 & 106.00 & 106.42 & 106.81 & 107.16 & 107.49 & 107.79 & 108.06 & 108.31 & 108.54 & 108.76 & 108.95 & 109.13 & 109.29 & 109.44 & 109.58 & 109.71 & 109.82 & 109.93 & 110.03 & 110.12 & 110.20 & 110.27 \\
10\% & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 \\
11\% & 99.10 & 98.29 & 97.56 & 96.90 & 96.30 & 95.77 & 95.29 & 94.85 & 94.46 & 94.11 & 93.79 & 93.51 & 93.25 & 93.02 & 92.81 & 92.62 & 92.45 & 92.30 & 92.16 & 92.04 & 91.92 & 91.82 & 91.73 & 91.65 & 91.58 & 91.51 & 91.45 & 91.40 & 91.35 & 91.31 \\
12\% & 98.21 & 96.62 & 95.20 & 93.93 & 92.79 & 91.78 & 90.87 & 90.06 & 89.34 & 88.70 & 88.12 & 87.61 & 87.15 & 86.74 & 86.38 & 86.05 & 85.76 & 85.50 & 85.27 & 85.06 & 84.88 & 84.71 & 84.56 & 84.43 & 84.31 & 84.21 & 84.11 & 84.03 & 83.96 & 83.89 \\
13\% & 97.35 & 95.00 & 92.92 & 91.08 & 89.45 & 88.01 & 86.73 & 85.60 & 84.61 & 83.72 & 82.94 & 82.25 & 81.63 & 81.09 & 80.61 & 80.19 & 79.81 & 79.48 & 79.19 & 78.93 & 78.70 & 78.49 & 78.31 & 78.15 & 78.01 & 77.88 & 77.77 & 77.68 & 77.59 & 77.51 \\
14\% & 96.49 & 93.41 & 90.71 & 88.35 & 86.27 & 84.45 & 82.85 & 81.44 & 80.21 & 79.14 & 78.19 & 77.36 & 76.63 & 75.99 & 75.43 & 74.94 & 74.51 & 74.13 & 73.80 & 73.51 & 73.25 & 73.03 & 72.83 & 72.66 & 72.51 & 72.38 & 72.26 & 72.16 & 72.07 & 71.99 \\
15\% & 95.65 & 91.87 & 88.58 & 85.73 & 83.24 & 81.08 & 79.20 & 77.56 & 76.14 & 74.91 & 73.83 & 72.90 & 72.08 & 71.38 & 70.76 & 70.23 & 69.76 & 69.36 & 69.01 & 68.70 & 68.44 & 68.21 & 68.01 & 67.83 & 67.68 & 67.55 & 67.43 & 67.33 & 67.25 & 67.17 \\
16\% & 94.83 & 90.37 & 86.52 & 83.21 & 80.35 & 77.89 & 75.77 & 73.94 & 72.36 & 71.00 & 69.83 & 68.82 & 67.95 & 67.19 & 66.55 & 65.99 & 65.51 & 65.09 & 64.74 & 64.43 & 64.16 & 63.93 & 63.73 & 63.56 & 63.42 & 63.29 & 63.18 & 63.09 & 63.01 & 62.94 \\
17\% & 94.02 & 88.90 & 84.53 & 80.80 & 77.60 & 74.88 & 72.54 & 70.55 & 68.85 & 67.39 & 66.15 & 65.08 & 64.17 & 63.39 & 62.73 & 62.16 & 61.68 & 61.26 & 60.91 & 60.61 & 60.35 & 60.13 & 59.94 & 59.77 & 59.64 & 59.52 & 59.42 & 59.33 & 59.26 & 59.19 \\
18\% & 93.22 & 87.47 & 82.61 & 78.48 & 74.98 & 72.02 & 69.51 & 67.38 & 65.58 & 64.05 & 62.75 & 61.65 & 60.72 & 59.94 & 59.27 & 58.70 & 58.22 & 57.81 & 57.47 & 57.18 & 56.93 & 56.72 & 56.54 & 56.39 & 56.26 & 56.16 & 56.06 & 55.99 & 55.92 & 55.87 \\
19\% & 92.44 & 86.08 & 80.74 & 76.25 & 72.48 & 69.31 & 66.65 & 64.41 & 62.53 & 60.95 & 59.62 & 58.51 & 57.57 & 56.78 & 56.12 & 55.56 & 55.09 & 54.70 & 54.37 & 54.09 & 53.86 & 53.66 & 53.50 & 53.36 & 53.24 & 53.15 & 53.06 & 52.99 & 52.94 & 52.89 \\
20\% & 91.67 & 84.72 & 78.94 & 74.11 & 70.09 & 66.74 & 63.95 & 61.63 & 59.69 & 58.08 & 56.73 & 55.61 & 54.67 & 53.89 & 53.25 & 52.70 & 52.25 & 51.88 & 51.57 & 51.30 & 51.09 & 50.91 & 50.75 & 50.63 & 50.52 & 50.44 & 50.36 & 50.30 & 50.25 & 50.21\\
\hline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption[test4]{test4}
 \begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc} \toprule
\hline\hline
YTM & 1Y & 2Y & 3Y & 4Y & 5Y & 6Y & 7Y & 8Y & 9Y & 10Y & 11Y & 12Y & 13Y & 14Y & 15Y & 16Y & 17Y & 18Y & 18Y & 20Y & 21Y & 22Y & 23Y & 24Y & 25Y & 26Y & 27Y & 28Y & 29Y & 30Y \\
\hline
0\%  & 90.91  & 82.64  & 75.13  & 68.30  & 62.09  & 56.45  & 51.32  & 46.65  & 42.41  & 38.55  & 35.05  & 31.86  & 28.97  & 26.33  & 23.94  & 21.76  & 19.78  & 17.99  & 16.35  & 14.86  & 13.51  & 12.28  & 11.17  & 10.15  & 9.23   & 8.39   & 7.63   & 6.93   & 6.30   & 5.73   \\
1\%  & 91.82  & 84.38  & 77.62  & 71.47  & 65.88  & 60.80  & 56.18  & 51.99  & 48.17  & 44.70  & 41.54  & 38.68  & 36.07  & 33.70  & 31.55  & 29.59  & 27.81  & 26.19  & 24.72  & 23.38  & 22.16  & 21.06  & 20.05  & 19.14  & 18.31  & 17.55  & 16.86  & 16.24  & 15.67  & 15.16  \\
2\%  & 92.73  & 86.12  & 80.11  & 74.64  & 69.67  & 65.16  & 61.05  & 57.32  & 53.93  & 50.84  & 48.04  & 45.49  & 43.17  & 41.07  & 39.15  & 37.41  & 35.83  & 34.39  & 33.08  & 31.89  & 30.81  & 29.83  & 28.93  & 28.12  & 27.38  & 26.71  & 26.10  & 25.55  & 25.04  & 24.58  \\
3\%  & 93.64  & 87.85  & 82.59  & 77.81  & 73.46  & 69.51  & 65.92  & 62.66  & 59.69  & 56.99  & 54.53  & 52.30  & 50.28  & 48.43  & 46.76  & 45.23  & 43.85  & 42.59  & 41.45  & 40.41  & 39.46  & 38.60  & 37.82  & 37.11  & 36.46  & 35.87  & 35.34  & 34.85  & 34.41  & 34.01  \\
4\%  & 94.55  & 89.59  & 85.08  & 80.98  & 77.26  & 73.87  & 70.79  & 67.99  & 65.45  & 63.13  & 61.03  & 59.12  & 57.38  & 55.80  & 54.36  & 53.06  & 51.87  & 50.79  & 49.81  & 48.92  & 48.11  & 47.37  & 46.70  & 46.09  & 45.54  & 45.03  & 44.58  & 44.16  & 43.78  & 43.44  \\
5\%  & 95.45  & 91.32  & 87.57  & 84.15  & 81.05  & 78.22  & 75.66  & 73.33  & 71.20  & 69.28  & 67.52  & 65.93  & 64.48  & 63.17  & 61.97  & 60.88  & 59.89  & 58.99  & 58.18  & 57.43  & 56.76  & 56.14  & 55.58  & 55.08  & 54.61  & 54.20  & 53.81  & 53.47  & 53.15  & 52.87  \\
6\%  & 96.36  & 93.06  & 90.05  & 87.32  & 84.84  & 82.58  & 80.53  & 78.66  & 76.96  & 75.42  & 74.02  & 72.75  & 71.59  & 70.53  & 69.58  & 68.71  & 67.91  & 67.19  & 66.54  & 65.95  & 65.41  & 64.91  & 64.47  & 64.06  & 63.69  & 63.36  & 63.05  & 62.77  & 62.52  & 62.29  \\
7\%  & 97.27  & 94.79  & 92.54  & 90.49  & 88.63  & 86.93  & 85.39  & 84.00  & 82.72  & 81.57  & 80.51  & 79.56  & 78.69  & 77.90  & 77.18  & 76.53  & 75.94  & 75.40  & 74.91  & 74.46  & 74.05  & 73.69  & 73.35  & 73.05  & 72.77  & 72.52  & 72.29  & 72.08  & 71.89  & 71.72  \\
8\%  & 98.18  & 96.53  & 95.03  & 93.66  & 92.42  & 91.29  & 90.26  & 89.33  & 88.48  & 87.71  & 87.01  & 86.37  & 85.79  & 85.27  & 84.79  & 84.35  & 83.96  & 83.60  & 83.27  & 82.97  & 82.70  & 82.46  & 82.23  & 82.03  & 81.85  & 81.68  & 81.53  & 81.39  & 81.26  & 81.15  \\
9\%  & 99.09  & 98.26  & 97.51  & 96.83  & 96.21  & 95.64  & 95.13  & 94.67  & 94.24  & 93.86  & 93.50  & 93.19  & 92.90  & 92.63  & 92.39  & 92.18  & 91.98  & 91.80  & 91.64  & 91.49  & 91.35  & 91.23  & 91.12  & 91.02  & 90.92  & 90.84  & 90.76  & 90.69  & 90.63  & 90.57  \\
10\% & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 & 100.00 \\
11\% & 100.91 & 101.74 & 102.49 & 103.17 & 103.79 & 104.36 & 104.87 & 105.33 & 105.76 & 106.14 & 106.50 & 106.81 & 107.10 & 107.37 & 107.61 & 107.82 & 108.02 & 108.20 & 108.36 & 108.51 & 108.65 & 108.77 & 108.88 & 108.98 & 109.08 & 109.16 & 109.24 & 109.31 & 109.37 & 109.43 \\
12\% & 101.82 & 103.47 & 104.97 & 106.34 & 107.58 & 108.71 & 109.74 & 110.67 & 111.52 & 112.29 & 112.99 & 113.63 & 114.21 & 114.73 & 115.21 & 115.65 & 116.04 & 116.40 & 116.73 & 117.03 & 117.30 & 117.54 & 117.77 & 117.97 & 118.15 & 118.32 & 118.47 & 118.61 & 118.74 & 118.85 \\
13\% & 102.73 & 105.21 & 107.46 & 109.51 & 111.37 & 113.07 & 114.61 & 116.00 & 117.28 & 118.43 & 119.49 & 120.44 & 121.31 & 122.10 & 122.82 & 123.47 & 124.06 & 124.60 & 125.09 & 125.54 & 125.95 & 126.31 & 126.65 & 126.95 & 127.23 & 127.48 & 127.71 & 127.92 & 128.11 & 128.28 \\
14\% & 103.64 & 106.94 & 109.95 & 112.68 & 115.16 & 117.42 & 119.47 & 121.34 & 123.04 & 124.58 & 125.98 & 127.25 & 128.41 & 129.47 & 130.42 & 131.29 & 132.09 & 132.81 & 133.46 & 134.05 & 134.59 & 135.09 & 135.53 & 135.94 & 136.31 & 136.64 & 136.95 & 137.23 & 137.48 & 137.71 \\
15\% & 104.55 & 108.68 & 112.43 & 115.85 & 118.95 & 121.78 & 124.34 & 126.67 & 128.80 & 130.72 & 132.48 & 134.07 & 135.52 & 136.83 & 138.03 & 139.12 & 140.11 & 141.01 & 141.82 & 142.57 & 143.24 & 143.86 & 144.42 & 144.92 & 145.39 & 145.80 & 146.19 & 146.53 & 146.85 & 147.13 \\
16\% & 105.45 & 110.41 & 114.92 & 119.02 & 122.74 & 126.13 & 129.21 & 132.01 & 134.55 & 136.87 & 138.97 & 140.88 & 142.62 & 144.20 & 145.64 & 146.94 & 148.13 & 149.21 & 150.19 & 151.08 & 151.89 & 152.63 & 153.30 & 153.91 & 154.46 & 154.97 & 155.42 & 155.84 & 156.22 & 156.56 \\
17\% & 106.36 & 112.15 & 117.41 & 122.19 & 126.54 & 130.49 & 134.08 & 137.34 & 140.31 & 143.01 & 145.47 & 147.70 & 149.72 & 151.57 & 153.24 & 154.77 & 156.15 & 157.41 & 158.55 & 159.59 & 160.54 & 161.40 & 162.18 & 162.89 & 163.54 & 164.13 & 164.66 & 165.15 & 165.59 & 165.99 \\
18\% & 107.27 & 113.88 & 119.89 & 125.36 & 130.33 & 134.84 & 138.95 & 142.68 & 146.07 & 149.16 & 151.96 & 154.51 & 156.83 & 158.93 & 160.85 & 162.59 & 164.17 & 165.61 & 166.92 & 168.11 & 169.19 & 170.17 & 171.07 & 171.88 & 172.62 & 173.29 & 173.90 & 174.45 & 174.96 & 175.42 \\
19\% & 108.18 & 115.62 & 122.38 & 128.53 & 134.12 & 139.20 & 143.82 & 148.01 & 151.83 & 155.30 & 158.46 & 161.32 & 163.93 & 166.30 & 168.45 & 170.41 & 172.19 & 173.81 & 175.28 & 176.62 & 177.84 & 178.94 & 179.95 & 180.86 & 181.69 & 182.45 & 183.14 & 183.76 & 184.33 & 184.84 \\
20\% & 109.09 & 117.36 & 124.87 & 131.70 & 137.91 & 143.55 & 148.68 & 153.35 & 157.59 & 161.45 & 164.95 & 168.14 & 171.03 & 173.67 & 176.06 & 178.24 & 180.22 & 182.01 & 183.65 & 185.14 & 186.49 & 187.72 & 188.83 & 189.85 & 190.77 & 191.61 & 192.37 & 193.07 & 193.70 & 194.27 \\
\hline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

One additional advise: Please note the difference between my code (which compiles and thus qualifies for a minimal working example) and yours.