# Reading a defined number of line from a file with **addplot**

Tags: pgfplots, external-files

I'm using `addplot` to create figures from an external `txt` file. I want  to create different figures, using an increasing number of lines of the data file. Obviously  i can create different data files with the requested rows, but it is not possible to gives some option to  `addplot table` so that it reads only the first $n$ rows of the file (something similar to the choice of the columns in a multicolumn file)?

My final goal is to build an animation using the different images so created and I have a file with more that $1000$ rows.

Comment: See, if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290025/two-large-sideways-tables-on-one-page, give you an idea, how to do this. Details you can find in manual for pgfplotstable, page 41.

Comment: Because you didn't provide a MWE I have nothing to play with, but couldn't you just use `skip coords between index` to get the desired result?